# Sending files in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, io, client-server, communication

I am quite new to Python and recently I wanted to send some files using Python. I quickly found out about sockets. But I searched for ready-made solution, because I thought client-server communication is such a common use, there must exist some kind of library (or maybe it's just because of my Java background and I got used to it:D). All answers about sending files I found mentioned sockets and that 'you have to write a protocol yourself'.

So here's my question: is there any library, ready protocol for client-server communication in Python (preferably 2.7)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

twisted is a very common one:

http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/

http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/13.0.0/core/examples/

Answer (score 0):

If you use sockets, you can use ssh and then do scp (secured copies).  If you are moving files back and forth, that would probably be the easiest way.

Comment: files for the most part, but I think there would be a lot of other activity, e.g. sending computations results or commands from one to another. So a flexible protocol would be a good thing here.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [zeromq](http://www.zeromq.org) is something for you! There are also [python bindings](http://www.zeromq.org/bindings%3apython) available. And good examples for implementing a [Publisher-Subscriber pattern](http://zguide.zeromq.org/py%3aall#Getting-the-Message-Out) are also well documented.

Answer (score 0):

*is there any library, ready protocol for client-server communication*

Generally speaking, yes: sockets (which you already found), twisted (as pointed in another answer) etc.

*I wanted to send some files using Python*

Use ftp! You can start an FTP server using [`pyftpdlib`](http://code.google.com/p/pyftpdlib/) and use [`ftplib`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html) as client.